# How to understand asynchronous code not IO bound

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have a gap in understand how the async code works for non-IO operations.
With IO it's obvious that that no thread is created since IO operations are controlled by netword cards, HDD or other things. But when I have some long-running method I need to make it as **Task.Run({method})**, but Task.Run() is actually creating/re-using a thread from pool and execution seems to me as parallel - the main thread and the thread-pool thread

Comment: What is your question? What you wrote so far is not wrong...

Comment: Agreed, it seems like you understand it just fine.

Comment: My question is - why the heck people say that async code DOES NOT use any another thread? All examples I see in the Internet are about File, HttpClient async methods. Maybe they meant only for IO-bound tasks.

Comment: @NickReshetinsky that's because it is generalizing something; in many (most?) cases, `async`/`await` *isn't* about threads; if you use `Task.Run`, then: yes, it is; that also doesn't mean that it can't still be useful!

Answer (score 4):

Even in the case when something is purely CPU bound, `async`/`await` can still be useful:

- not all threads are equal; in client-side apps, it is *hugely* beneficial to release the UI thread back to doing things like painting and responding to event-loop events, while other work continues in the background; this can be done in many ways, one of which is: `async`/`await`; alternatively - some threads might work with different priorities
- sometimes you can usefully parallelize work, whether to compute something else while the worker thread things, or perhaps to split a single piece of work between *many* threads; in either case `async`/`await` *can* be used to coordinate ("join") those operations
- however: if these scenarios don't apply, and you're pushing work between threads *just* to `await` it (without doing anything else concurrently, and without any special thread conditions) - then you're *just* adding overheads by using `async`/`await`